# Is it a good practice to call an instance method in the constructor of the object that holds the method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Example:

```
public class EmailBusinessLogic
{
    #region Fields and Constructors
    SmtpClient smtp;
    Parameter prm;

    public EmailBusinessLogic()
    {
        prm = CostHelper.GetParameter();
        smtp = new SmtpClient(prm.EmailHost, prm.EmailPort);
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = prm.EmailUseDefaultCredentials;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = GetDeliveryMethod(prm.EmailDeliveryMethod); //CALL TO METHOD DOWN BELOW, IS THIS A GOOD PRACTICE?
        smtp.EnableSsl = prm.EmailEnableSSL;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(prm.AppUserName, prm.AppPass, prm.AppNetworkDomain);

    }
    #endregion

    #region Instance Methods
    public SmtpDeliveryMethod GetDeliveryMethod(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Network": return SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            case "IISDirectory": return SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
            case "OtherDirectory": return SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
            default: throw new NonExistentObjectException();
        }
    }
```

I am asking this because its a small paradox, i know the constructor always gets called first when instantiating this class into a new object. And i would not want to make it a static method because that will create a static instance that does not get garbage collected.

If i am wrong please correct me, a clear answer from an experienced fellow programmer is highly welcome. Thank you.

Comment: A static *method* will not cause any additional memory to be used. (Nothing more than the equivalent instance method - the code exists in the assembly, gets JITted, etc.)

Comment: Noted. Thank you. So regarding this matter only if you create a static class that one will indeed remain in the memory. Is this a true statement?

Comment: I would make that method static, because it's really just a "translation" from `String` to `SmtpDeliveryMethod` and it does not use any instance information from the object. Like Andrew Russell I think you confuse static methods with static fields. What is that you fear will not be garbage collected?

Comment: @Freeman there is no "that one" - static methods do not create any instance. You seem to be thinking of a singleton - unrelated.

Comment: ok, more specifically if i had a variable in the GetDelivery Method would that remain in memory? thats what im also not sure about.

Comment: @Freeman Of course, if you have variable in the GetDelivery Method's scope, it would live only till the method returns, no matter static or instance said method is

Comment: Thanks Roger, now its all clear, thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Freeman method variables (locals) are (in most cases, the exceptions won't be useful to this discussion) allocated **on the stack**, and live as long as the method-call only. No heap memory is involved..

Comment: @Roger that isn't really garbage collection as such

Comment: Now i got it, as soon as the method exits it just 'pops' from the stack, Correct?

Comment: @MarcGravell indeed, corrected

Comment: @Freeman BTW, your `GetDeliveryMethod` is a prime candidate to be moved to some utility class and made static. It's simple and keeping it inside EmailBusinessLogic looks like not a very good design for me. I mean if you want to make a unit-test of how string-names are translated into `SmtpDeliveryMethod` - you need to create the whole  `EmailBusinessLogic`object, which will in turn create not needed (for that particular test) `SmtpClient` and `Parameter` objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling a non-static method in the constructor *can* be ok - but you should avoid it for virtual methods, because if the method is overridden the *actual* method will be called on a type that hasn't had the type-level constructor invoked yet - can cause problems.

Calling a static method would be more reliable. I think your reasons for *not* wanting a static method are a bit confused, and do not apply. There is absolutely no reason to avoid a static method. A static method is not implemented as an instance method on a "static instance that does not get garbage collected". There *is no instance* for a static method.

Comment: Thank you very much Marc, your answer was swift and clear. Have a nice day.